# WORDNET: Mysql and subcategories

Tags: mysql, wordnet

I have a list of words. I would like to automatically be able to retrieve the number of subcategories from wordnet for each of these words. How would you do this?

I am also looking for a mysql version of wordnet but can't find one anywhere. Would you know where to find one?

Best,

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this WordNetSQL builder](http://wnsqlbuilder.sourceforge.net/). You should be able to build it out if you follow the download link.

Regarding subcategories, you'd use Wordnet's **hyponyms** - given a concept, it gives you the concepts that are more specific.
The hyponyms of "Car" would be "hatchback", "compact" etc.
Take a look [at this part of the NLTK book.](http://nltk.org/book/ch02.html#fig-wn-hierarchy)

Comment: From the Wordnet MySQL database, can you tell me how to extract example sentences for a given word?

Comment: @AttitudeMonger I suggest that you post this as a separate question. You will get answers from the community.

Comment: Done that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601052/wordnet-query-to-return-example-sentences :)