# Wordnet query to return example sentences

Tags: mysql, sql, words, wordnet, lexicon

I have a use case where I have a word and I need to know the following things:

1. Synonyms for the word (just the synonyms are sufficient)
2. All senses of the word, where each sense contains - the synonyms matching that word in that sense, example sentences in that sense (if there), the part of speech for that sense.

Example - [this query link](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=carry&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=). Screenshot for the word `carry`:

[image]

For each 'sense', we have the part of speech (like `V`), synonyms matching that sense, (like `transport` in the first sense, `pack`, `take` in the second sense, etc), example sentences containing that word in that sense (`This train is carrying nuclear waste`, `carry the suitcase to the car`, etc in first sense, `I always carry money` etc in the second sense, etc.).

How do I do this from a [Wordnet MySQL database](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wnsql/files/)? I ran this query, it returns the list of meanings for the word:

`SELECT  a.lemma, c.definition FROM  words a INNER JOIN senses b ON a.wordid = b.wordid INNER JOIN synsets c ON b.synsetid = c.synsetid WHERE   a.lemma = 'carry';`

How do I get the synonyms, example sentences, part of speech and synonyms specific to that sense for each sense? I queried the `vframesentences` and `vframesentencemaps` tables, saw example sentences with placeholders like `%s`, and based on the `wordid` column I tried to match them with the `words` table, but got awfully wrong results.

Edit:

For the word `carry`, if I run these queries, I get synonyms and sense meanings correctly:

```
1. select * from words where lemma='carry' //yield wordid as 21354
2. select * from senses where wordid=21354 //yield 41 sysnsetids, like 201062889
3. select * from synsets where synsetid=201062889 //yields the explanation "serve as a means for expressing something"
4. select * from senses where synsetid=20106288` /yields all matching synonyms for that sense as wordids, including "carry" - like 21354, 29630, 45011
5. select * from words where wordid=29630 //yields 'convey'
```

So all I now need is a way of finding the example sentence for the word `carry` in each of the 41 senses. How do I do it?

Comment: What does "c.definition" give you? I'm not familiar with WordNet database. I can help you more if you give me online documentation about how wordnet database tables look like. "c.definition" gives you a list of bullet points like the following?

`S: (v) transport, carry (move while supporting, either in a vehicle or in one's hands or on one's body) "You must carry your camping gear"; "carry the suitcases  ..."`
`S: (v) carry, pack, take (have with oneself; have on one's person) "She always takes an umbrella"; "I always carry money"; "She packs ..."
...`

Comment: I think `definition` provides just the definition..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the sentences from the `samples` table. E.g:

```
SELECT sample FROM samples WHERE synsetid = 201062889;
```

yields:

> The painting of Mary carries motherly love
>
> His voice carried a lot of anger

So you could extend your query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    a.lemma AS `word`,
    c.definition,
    c.pos AS `part of speech`,
    d.sample AS `example sentence`,
    (SELECT 
            GROUP_CONCAT(a1.lemma)
        FROM
            words a1
                INNER JOIN
            senses b1 ON a1.wordid = b1.wordid
        WHERE
            b1.synsetid = b.synsetid
                AND a1.lemma <> a.lemma
        GROUP BY b.synsetid) AS `synonyms`
FROM
    words a
        INNER JOIN
    senses b ON a.wordid = b.wordid
        INNER JOIN
    synsets c ON b.synsetid = c.synsetid
        INNER JOIN
    samples d ON b.synsetid = d.synsetid
WHERE
    a.lemma = 'carry'
ORDER BY a.lemma , c.definition , d.sample;
```

Note: The subselect with a `GROUP_CONCAT` returns the synonyms of each sense as a comma-separated list in a single row in order to cut down on the number of rows. You could consider returning these in a separate query (or as part of this query but with everything else duplicated) if preferred.

**UPDATE**
If you really need synonyms as rows in the results, the following will do it but I wouldn't recommend it: Synonyms and example sentences both pertain to a particular definition so the set of synonyms will be duplicated for each example sentence. E.g. if there are 4 example sentences and 5 synonyms for a particular definition, the results would have 4 x 5 = 20 rows just for that definition.

```
SELECT 
    a.lemma AS `word`,
    c.definition,
    c.pos AS `part of speech`,
    d.sample AS `example sentence`,
    subq.lemma AS `synonym`
FROM
    words a
        INNER JOIN
    senses b ON a.wordid = b.wordid
        INNER JOIN
    synsets c ON b.synsetid = c.synsetid
        INNER JOIN
    samples d ON b.synsetid = d.synsetid
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        a1.lemma, b1.synsetid
    FROM
        senses b1
    INNER JOIN words a1 ON a1.wordid = b1.wordid) subq ON subq.synsetid = b.synsetid
        AND subq.lemma <> a.lemma
WHERE
    a.lemma = 'carry'
ORDER BY a.lemma , c.definition , d.sample;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks. You are right, I need the synonyms separately, let the results be duplicated. Of course I can get them in a separate query, or make it ugly and extract/comma parse the result to get individual synonyms, but better if they come from the query itself. Or is it guaranteed that no synonym will not contain commas?

Comment: By the way, the synonyms that return are all lower-cased. But in actual website if you search for say `Jesus`, it returns results like `Christ`, `Deliverer` etc all capitalized. How do I get properly cased synonyms?

Comment: Synonyms are just words and none contain commas: `SELECT lemma FROM words WHERE lemma LIKE '%,%';` returns no results. Have updated the answer to include a way of getting synonyms for each sense in individual rows. Re: Capitalization - unfortunately this seems to be how the words are stored in the database (see mysql-wn-data.sql) so there's not much that can be done other than applying capitalization to all synonyms. Only thing to suggest is perhaps try a different [database flavour](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wnsql/files/wnsql3/) (sqlite / standard) and see if it has the same issue.

Comment: By the way, it is not related to this question, but still want to know, how do I find different forms of the same word? For example, the word `show` is absent in the table `words`. However its other form `show` is there. How do I query something like if one form is not there, return the form present?

Comment: And even common words like `and`, `is` are missing. Can Wordnet return their meanings in any way?

Comment: how to get only few rows from the result ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to limit the number of rows returned? If so, use a [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html#idm139630354050064) clause.