# Select change column value if in list

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, case

I am trying to query my table to count the number of votes and if the voting method is in list `['C', 'M', 'S', 'L', 'T', 'V', 'B', 'E']` then count it as one and replace the voting_method to 'L'.

Right now I have the following query which returns the right results but doesn't take care of the duplicates.

```
select `election_lbl`, `voting_method`, count(*) as numVotes 
from `gen2014` group by `election_lbl`, `voting_method` order by `election_lbl` asc 

election_lbl voting_method numVotes
2014-09-04   M                    1
2014-09-05   M                    2
2014-09-05   S                    1
2014-09-08   C                   16
2014-09-08   M                    5
2014-09-08   S                    9
2014-09-09   10                   5
2014-09-09   C                   46
2014-09-09   M                    4
2014-09-09   S                    5
2014-09-10   C                   92
2014-0g-10   M                    3
2014-09-10   S                    7
2014-09-11   C                   96
2014-09-11   M                    3
2014-09-11   S                    2
2014-09-12   C                  104
2014-09-12   M                   10
2014-09-12   S                    3
2014-09-15   C                  243
2014-09-15   M                   18
2014-09-15   S                    3
2014-09-16   10                   1
2014-09-16   C                  161
2014-09-16   M                    4
2014-09-16   S                    3
2014-09-17   C                  157
2014-09-17   M                    5
2014-09-17   S                   12
```

You can see that for 2014-09-05 I have two voting_method M and S both of which is in the list. I want the ideal result to remove the duplicate date field if the values are in the list. So it would be 2014-09-05 'L' 3. I don't want the vote for that date to disappear so the results should count them as one.

Changed the query to this but mysql says wrong syntax.

```
select `election_lbl`, `voting_method`, count(*) as numVotes from `gen2014`
(case `voting_method` when in ('C', 'M', 'S', 'L', 'T', 'V', 'B', 'E') 
then 'L' END) group by `election_lbl`, `voting_method` order by `election_lbl` asc
```

Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `gen2014` (
 `voting_method` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `election_lbl` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: `in` is basically an operator, the proper syntax should be `case when voting method in .... then ...`; though I can't think of any reason the query should need to be so complicated (unless you also want the numVotes for methods not in the list as well).

Comment: I actually do need the numVotes of the methods not in the list. The goal is to count the ones in the list as 'L' and leave the rest as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT election_lbl
     , CASE WHEN voting_method IN ('C','M','S','L','T','V','B','E')
            THEN 'L' 
            ELSE voting_method END my_voting_method
     , COUNT(*) 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY my_voting_method    -- or vice
     , election_lbl;       -- versa
```

Comment: Thank you. That did solved it. I am stuck with another mysql problem as well. maybe you can solve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104350/wordnet-mysql-synonyms-and-samples

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the total votes using those methods for each date, listed as method 'L', then do not include method in the `group by`, and have the `SELECT` select `'L' as voting_method`

```
select `election_lbl`, 'L' AS `voting_method`, count(*) as numVotes 
from `gen2014` 
where voting_method IN ('C', 'M', 'S', 'L', 'T', 'V', 'B', 'E')
group by `election_lbl`
order by `election_lbl` asc
```

Comment: I need the numVotes of the methods not in the list too. The goal is to count the ones in the list as 'L' and leave the rest as is.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi looks like Strawberry's answer is the way to go then.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you can solve this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104350/wordnet-mysql-synonyms-and-samples

Answer (score 0):

```
select x.`election_lbl`, x.`voting_method`, count(*) as numVotes 
from (
       select `election_lbl`, 
       CASE when `voting_method` in ('C', 'M', 'S', 'L', 'T', 'V', 'B', 'E') 
            then 'L' 
            else `voting_method` 
       END as `voting_method` 
       from `gen2014`) x
group by x.`election_lbl`, x.`voting_method` 
order by x.`election_lbl` asc
```

Comment: .Got this error. Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: I have added the alias.