# understand Wordnet sqlite database

Tags: database, sqlite, nlp, wordnet

I have downloaded Wordnet sqlite [sqlite-31.db.zip] [https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_wnsql/][1](https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_wnsql/)

The file looks like [image]

I can not understand the file. I have a project where I have to use this. But i can't figure it out. what's the meaning of this number?

> ex: 5351 4c69 7465

please help!

Comment: You need a SQL client tool to connect to the database (e.g. the `sqlite` [command line client](http://sqlite.org/cli.html)). Then use [SQL statements](http://sqlite.org/lang.html) to look at the data.

Comment: Once you have sqlite installed and working, as described in Lutz's answer, you might find this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37104350/841830

Answer (score 4):

You will need the [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html) command line tool ([download](https://sqlite.org/download.html)). Then you can inspect the database file.

```
% sqlite3 sqlite-31.db        
SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE adjpositions (synsetid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',wordid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',position CHARACTER (2) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT pk_adjpositions PRIMARY KEY (synsetid,wordid));
CREATE TABLE adjpositiontypes (position CHARACTER (2) NOT NULL,positionname VARCHAR (24) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT pk_adjpositiontypes PRIMARY KEY (position));
CREATE TABLE casedwords (casedwordid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',wordid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',cased VARCHAR (80) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT pk_casedwords PRIMARY KEY (casedwordid));
CREATE TABLE lexdomains (lexdomainid SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',lexdomainname VARCHAR (32) DEFAULT NULL,lexdomain VARCHAR (32) DEFAULT NULL,pos CHARACTER (1) DEFAULT NULL,CONSTRAINT pk_lexdomains PRIMARY KEY (lexdomainid));
...
sqlite> select count(*) from adjpositions;
1054
sqlite>
```

Comment: I have downloaded SQLite command line tool. when i open SQLite3 it shows this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw6SB.png . How can i inspect the database file? @Lutz Horn

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: ` sqlite3 sqlite-31.db`